# Why is it giving wrong image in .aspx?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am new to asp.net platform. In our website, each time user clicks on a button a new image is created and it overwrites already existing file "result.png". But each time, it gives wrong  image file.
code is here:

```
<p>Click <a href="../../Images/result.png">here</a> to view the last travelled path</p>
```

But if I just put the same code snippet in a sample.html file and run each time I get the latest image. Why is it so? How can I resolve this?

I am guessing there is a cached image. and it is returning that always. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try busting the cache by appending a random query string parameter:

```
<p>
    Click 
    <a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/result.png?_=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()) %>">
        here
    </a> 
    to view the last travelled path
</p>
```